# Checkbox size after text width

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this

```
CreateWindowA("BUTTON", "Testing!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, 0, 0, 45, 20, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
```

and the checkbox text does not fit inside the checkbox size.

[image: CB Testing!]

Can i somehow set the checkbox width after the text width?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Why don't you just pass in a different width instead of adjusting the size afterwards?

Comment: You can calculate the text size you need using `GetTextExtentPoint32`, then just add the width of the checkbox itself.

Comment: @EddyLuten I want the size to be dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GetTextExtentPoint32` to get the size of the string, then you need to add the size of the checkbox itself by using `GetSystemMetrics` with SM_CXMENUCHECK:

```
HDC hDc = GetDC(hWnd);
HFONT hCurrentFont;
HFONT hNewFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT); //Change this if you want to use a different font!
if(hCurrentFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDc, hNewFont))
{
    SIZE stringSize;
    if(GetTextExtentPoint32A(hDc, "Testing!", sizeof("Testing!"), &stringSize))
    {
        int totalWidth = stringSize.cx + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
        int totalHeight = stringSize.cy;
        CreateWindowA("BUTTON", "Testing!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, 
                          0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight, hWnd, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        //error! unable to get size
    }
}
else
{
    //error! unable to get font
}
hNewFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDc, hCurrentFont);

DeleteObject(hNewFont);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDc); //Release DC
```

Comment: The concept is right but two things are wrong with your example - the DC you get from `GetDC` will be leaked, and you need to select the correct font into the DC before calculating the text size. Will +1 if you fix those.

Comment: Good call, silly me thought I could one-off some Win32 code quickly before heading home.  Edited.

Comment: `GetTextExtentPoint32()` third argument expects string length (number of characters). `sizeof()` returns data bytes that can mismatch characters number. Maybe `strlen()` is better.

Answer (score 8):

Found this wonderful message deep in some MSDN browsing!

`BCM_GETIDEALSIZE`

```
HWND cbhwnd = CreateWindowA("BUTTON", "Testing!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
SIZE size;
SendMessage(cbhwnd, BCM_GETIDEALSIZE, 0, &size);
SendMessage(cbhwnd, WM_SIZE, 0, size);
```

Comment: Do note that `BCM_GETIDEALSIZE` only applies to XP and later with ComCtrl v6 visual styles enabled.